# Update stock level in a particular warehouse

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, inventory, cataloginventory

We have multiple warehouses for our web-store and we want to update stock via script whenever we get new stock in. However, when I try to update the stock level via program, the stock level goes up superficially but stock in the warehouse remains to show "0". This is a major problem and creates stock issues in our website.

I am attaching a snapshot for you to see what the issue is:

[image: Stock issue]

As you can see, the stock itself within the Product attributes state it is 22, however it's value within the warehouse stock = 0. How can I go about updating the stock value in the specific warehouse programmatically?

When I try to update stock via the following code :

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($xyzModel->getId());
            $stockItem->setData('qty', $newQty);
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', $newInStock);
            $stockItem->save();
```

It only updates the stock superficially, as shown in the photo.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this bit of code. Please make sure your paths to files are full paths (especially if you are going to run cronjobs, otherwise this wont work)

Create a file and add the following:

```
<?php 

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
require_once '/var/www/html/website/httpdocs/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app(); 


// Function to read each line of csv file seperately
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024, ';');
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}

$csvFile = '/var/www/html/website/httpdocs/csv-with-stock-and-sku.csv';
$csvdata = readCSV($csvFile);



/* UPDATE PRICES */
foreach($csvdata as $data){
    $sku = $data[9]; //SKU
    $stock = $data[6]; //STOCK

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
    if ($product) {
        $productId = $product->getId();
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
        $stockItem->setData('qty', $stock);

        if($stock <= 0){
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 0);
        } else{
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
        }

        $stockItem->save();
        unset($stockItem);
        unset($product);
    }
}?>
```